Convert jks keystore to bouncy castle fips compliant format with expired keys
I'm trying to get an application running on a RHEL8 server using Apache Tomcat 9. The application launches as soon as I turn FIPS mode off on my server. So I suspect it has something to do with the keystore not being FIPS compliant.
I noticed that when I performed the keytool -list command, many of the entries in my keystore were expired. Will FIPS compliance automatically fail because of an expired keystore even if it's converted into a BCFKS format? Also, I'm a little confused on the implementation of BouncyCastle bcfks format. Is the idea that it will take a non FIPS compliant jks keystore an make it FIPS compliant? Or are there other factors involved that determine if the keystore is FIPS compliant?
I would greatly appreciate in help or suggestions here. Thank you.
I'm attempting to use the bcprov-jdk-1.64.jar file to convert .jks format into a .bcfks format. I also placed the jar file in the lib directory "JRE_HOME/lib/ext" and edited my java.security file to include an entry for security.provider.N=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
Basically, I followed this documentation:
https://tomee.apache.org/bouncy-castle.html
I then used the following keytool command to convert my .jks files into the .bcfks format:

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore trust.jks -srcstoretype JKS -srcstorepass  -destkeystore trust.bcfks -deststorepass  -deststoretype BCFKS -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath ./BouncyCastle/bcprov-jdk15on-1.64.jar

I updated my server.xml with the keystore format of "BCFKS".
